# Books for learning Python 3(For data analysis)

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I am relatively new in Python, and my goal is to develop my Python's skills for data analysis. I have basic skills in Python 3 Programming language, but i want to become very good in this sphere.
I have read one book about programming in Python(John Zelle) and i posses basic skills, but for example i didn't get the idea of OOP.
So, can you please recommend me literature for learning Python(for data analysis)?
Or before diving in such concrete sphere should i begin with general book?
So fom what should I begin?
Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are other sites that welcome this kind of question. There's a subreddit for python learners, for example. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/wiki/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you begin by taking a look at the basic python libraries for data analysis and plotting, such as the following:

- [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)
- [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

That will give you a good start on data analysis with Python. If you want a book, take this one:

- Python for Data Analysis, by Wes McKinney

Answer (score 0):

For beginners I would suggest  -  " **Python for Data Analysis
Data Wrangling with Pandas, NumPy, and IPython By William McKinney**" which is packed with practical cases studies. It’s ideal for analysts new to Python and for Python programmers new to scientific computing.
In addition you can check this book that focuses more on machine learning - " **Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: A Guide for Data Scientists: Andreas C. MÃ¼ller, Sarah Guido.** "

Hope that helps! All the best!